# Create random list of integers in Python

Tags: python, list, random, performance

I'd like to create a random list of integers for testing purposes. The distribution of the numbers is not important. The only thing that is counting is **time**. I know generating random numbers is a time-consuming task, but there must be a better way.

Here's my current solution:

```
import random
import timeit

# Random lists from [0-999] interval
print [random.randint(0, 1000) for r in xrange(10)] # v1
print [random.choice([i for i in xrange(1000)]) for r in xrange(10)] # v2

# Measurement:
t1 = timeit.Timer('[random.randint(0, 1000) for r in xrange(10000)]', 'import random') # v1
t2 = timeit.Timer('random.sample(range(1000), 10000)', 'import random') # v2

print t1.timeit(1000)/1000
print t2.timeit(1000)/1000
```

v2 is faster than v1, but it is not working on such a large scale. It gives the following error:

> **ValueError: sample larger than population**

Is there a fast, efficient solution that works at that scale?

#### Some results from the answer

Andrew's: 0.000290962934494

gnibbler's: 0.0058455221653

KennyTM's: 0.00219276118279

NumPy came, saw, and conquered.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. `random.sample()` depletes the population, making the numbers less and less random. Once the entire population is depleted, it's impossible to sample further.

Comment: When you say it's for testing purposes, how long will the testing take?

Comment: For simulations, where time is a requirement (but crypto and security are not), then a [Linear Congruential Generator (LCG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) is often used. I believe a [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) is fast (but slower than LCG), and it provides a uniform distribution, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you want, but I would use [numpy.random.randint](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
import numpy.random as nprnd
import timeit

t1 = timeit.Timer('[random.randint(0, 1000) for r in xrange(10000)]', 'import random') # v1

### Change v2 so that it picks numbers in (0, 10000) and thus runs...
t2 = timeit.Timer('random.sample(range(10000), 10000)', 'import random') # v2
t3 = timeit.Timer('nprnd.randint(1000, size=10000)', 'import numpy.random as nprnd') # v3

print t1.timeit(1000)/1000
print t2.timeit(1000)/1000
print t3.timeit(1000)/1000
```

which gives on my machine:

```
0.0233682730198
0.00781716918945
0.000147947072983
```

Note that randint is *very* different from random.sample (in order for it to work in your case I had to change the 1,000 to 10,000 as one of the commentators pointed out -- if you really want them from 0 to 1,000 you could divide by 10).

And if you really don't care what distribution you are getting then it is possible that you either don't understand your problem very well, or random numbers -- with apologies if that sounds rude...

Comment: +1 for numpy, if Stiggo needs this many random numbers it's probably worth installing numpy just for this

Comment: Andrew, you absolutely right about distribution. But this is not a real thing. Just a challange between friends. :D
Cheers!

Answer (score 34):

All the random methods end up calling `random.random()` so the best way is to call it directly:

```
[int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10000)]
```

For example,

- `random.randint` calls `random.randrange`.
- `random.randrange` has a bunch of overhead to check the range before returning `istart + istep*int(self.random() * n)`.

NumPy is much faster still of course.

Comment: +1 I was just digging through it all earlier and ended up thinking that `randrange` eventually led to a call to `getrandbits`. I missed that you have to instantiate `SystemRandom` for that to be the behavior. Thanks for making me look more closely.

Comment: Your's beat my version, but Andrew's solution clearly the winner.

Comment: @Stiggo, for sure, the only reason I can think not to use numpy would be if numpy isn't supported on your platform. eg. google app engine

Comment: in Python3, random.randrange(1000) is designed to produce a more uniform distribution than random.random()*1000.  See section 9.6.2 here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: @AlexeyPolonsky, nice pickup. If we are happy to take numbers up to 1023, then `[getrandbits(10) for r in range(10000)]` is 9 times faster than the list comprehension in my answer

Comment: @JohnLaRooy thanks! This is actually even more useful!

Comment: `xrange` was renamed to `range` in python 3

Answer (score 6):

Your question about performance is moot—both functions are very fast. The speed of your code will be determined by what you *do* with the random numbers.

However it's important you understand the difference in *behaviour* of those two functions. One does random sampling with replacement, the other does random sampling without replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should use `randrange(0,1000)` or `randint(0,999)`, not `randint(0,1000)`. The upper limit of `randint` is inclusive.

For efficiently, `randint` is simply a wrapper of `randrange` which calls `random`, so you should just use `random`. Also, use `xrange` as the argument to `sample`, not `range`.

You could use

```
[a for a in sample(xrange(1000),1000) for _ in range(10000/1000)]
```

to generate 10,000 numbers in the range using `sample` 10 times.

(Of course this won't beat NumPy.)

```
$ python2.7 -m timeit -s 'from random import randrange' '[randrange(1000) for _ in xrange(10000)]'
10 loops, best of 3: 26.1 msec per loop

$ python2.7 -m timeit -s 'from random import sample' '[a%1000 for a in sample(xrange(10000),10000)]'
100 loops, best of 3: 18.4 msec per loop

$ python2.7 -m timeit -s 'from random import random' '[int(1000*random()) for _ in xrange(10000)]' 
100 loops, best of 3: 9.24 msec per loop

$ python2.7 -m timeit -s 'from random import sample' '[a for a in sample(xrange(1000),1000) for _ in range(10000/1000)]'
100 loops, best of 3: 3.79 msec per loop

$ python2.7 -m timeit -s 'from random import shuffle
> def samplefull(x):
>   a = range(x)
>   shuffle(a)
>   return a' '[a for a in samplefull(1000) for _ in xrange(10000/1000)]'
100 loops, best of 3: 3.16 msec per loop

$ python2.7 -m timeit -s 'from numpy.random import randint' 'randint(1000, size=10000)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 363 usec per loop
```

---

But since you don't care about the distribution of numbers, why not just use:

```
range(1000)*(10000/1000)
```

?

Comment: `randrange(1000)` takes more than twice as long as `1000*int(random())` on my computer

Comment: What is the purpose of `10000/1000`?