# Best way to generate random number with uniform distribution?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, random, rounding, random-seed

What is the best way to generate random numbers with a   using Python 3.5 on Linux, to have the more random number as possible the pseudo-generator can give us.

I have seeded my random generator like this:

`random.seed(a=os.urandom(512), version=2)`

Then I am trying to fill up an array with binary values [0,1]:

```
randarray=[]

for i in range(X): randarray.append(        int (round(random.uniform(0, 1) ,0))                )
```

Am I doing this correctly, if not please help me out.

Comment: You can use `random.randint(0, 1)`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I need uniform numbers though. I am not sure how well does python de-bias the numbers, do you recommend generating biased numbers and then debiasing it ourselves?

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% certain about that. There will always be some degree of non-uniformity in any generated random number. But you can verify the _degree of randomness_ with a simple chi-squared test. There are python modules for that.

Comment: Also see [Create random list of integers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172131/608639)