Is there a way to generate numbers in a complete random, unpredictable way?
When I was learning about random number generation, I figured out that the output often follows a guided way (for example, a point on a gaussian distribution). While this looks random enough, it is not "random".
After investigating, I define a random number generation method "random" by:

Generate a 5d.p. decimal
Store the decimal
Run the generation again
Store the time of generation required for the generation to generate the same one stores
If the above steps are repeated for 31 times, and by central limit theorem, it follows a normal distribution, it is not random enough
If not, then try generating 6 d.p.
Infinitely repeat the above steps until the result showed in 8. Have a steady rate of occurrence.
An ideal random number generation should have equal probability for all numbers.


Actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872074/best-way-to-generate-random-number-with-uniform-distribution is close enough, but it does not satisfy 7. even if it approaches 8. .

Short answer, yes this is possible. But you're on the wrong track. Longer answer. Really smart people have thought about this, and their best answer is available on Unix systems at /dev/random. But this can be slow, and there are very few cases where you need that. It is better to seed a random number generator from true randomness and use that instead. This is at /dev/urandom. Really long answer, read https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/.

A "random" number is an abstract concept that only has relevance in mathematics. There is no way to prove that seemingly random events observed in nature are in fact random. Nor are we humans able to construct devices that generate truly random events, such as machines that stir numbered ping-pong balls. The best we can do to generate so called "pseudo-random" numbers (sometimes called "sorta-random" or "kinda-random" numbers) within a range, which are constructs that do not fail certain statistical tests that have been developed. In your title "complete" and "unpredictable" are superfluous.

https://api.random.org/dashboard "randomness comes from atmospheric noise", how random are you talking?

Computers are not random devices, so for a random output you need a random input. That is possible with quantum mechanics, for example radioactive decay - connect a Geiger counter to an input port. Alternatively look for a cryptographically secure RNG, like Fortuna.

You are coming from an assumption that, rephrased, is more or less "if it follows normal distribution, it is not random". This is entirely wrong and invalidates the rest of the question. Sanity check: do a series of 10-dice rolls and observe that their sum follows normal distribution. In fact, the more randomness you add (more dice), the more perfect of a match to a gaussian you get. The same logic applies to any other distribution, too

Thanks for all the suggestions, I am able to optimise my random model. THX!!!
